# Need to pass dynamic collection name and column name in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query in which I have to give the collection name and field name dynamically. I want to get only selected column not all columns in collection. The query is for mongodb. Query is given below

`var cursor = database.GetCollection<ExpandoObject>(item.TableName).Find(Builders<ExpandoObject>.Filter.Exists(item.FieldName)).ToList();`